# Apply one groupby value back to all group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I have a table

```
 id    valid
 1      book
 1      unknown
 1      unknown
 2      unknown
 2      book
 2      unknown
 3      unknown
 3      unknown
 3      book
 4      unknown
 4      picture
```

I picked some `id` and test whether the item is valid. If it has been validated, the `valid` column will be 'book'. But some item's `valid` column are still 'unknown'. I want them to become 'book'. As they are not all appearing in the first place of each group, I cannot use something like `groupby.first()`. And since the position of `unknown` is not fixed, I cannot use something like `apply(pd.DataFrame.last_valid_index)`.

And since my original table is vary large, I do not prefer loops.

The desired column should be looks like:

```
 id    valid
 1      book
 1      book
 1      book
 2      book
 2      book
 2      book
 3      book
 3      book
 3      book
 4      unknown
 4      picture
```

Comment: Sorry I have changed the 1 and 0 to strings, to be more general.

Comment: I updated the id '4'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform` and return a scalar or Series in the `lambda` function based on your need:

```
df['valid'] = df.valid.groupby(df.id).transform(lambda g: 'book' if g.eq('book').any() else g)

df
#    id    valid
#0    1     book
#1    1     book
#2    1     book
#3    2     book
#4    2     book
#5    2     book
#6    3     book
#7    3     book
#8    3     book
#9    4  unknown
#10   4  picture
```

Comment: Does this only apply to numbers like 0 or 1? My table contains some strings.

Comment: Can you show some real data? My guess is you need to do something like `transform(lambda g: ...)` but return a scalar in the `lambda` function.

Comment: I ll modified the question, please view it later.

Comment: Your answer is good, but if there are more than two strings? Could I change the else part and make them stay what they used to be? See my updates. Sorry for continuously asking...

Comment: Cheers I should look at that function. And I have figured it out. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie I noticed you changed your question midway. Please refrain from doing that in future, it is disrespectful to those who invested time into addressing your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace 0 to np.nan , then using `ffill` and `bfill`

```
df.valid=df.valid.replace(0,np.nan)
df.valid=df.groupby('id').valid.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()).fillna(0)
df
Out[1078]: 
    id  valid
0    1    1.0
1    1    1.0
2    1    1.0
3    2    1.0
4    2    1.0
5    2    1.0
6    3    1.0
7    3    1.0
8    3    1.0
9    4    0.0
10   4    0.0
```

Update ......op ,since change the question

```
s=df.loc[df.valid=='book','id']
pd.concat([df[df.id.isin(s)].replace('unknown','book'),df[~df.id.isin(s)]])
Out[1126]: 
    id    valid
0    1     book
1    1     book
2    1     book
3    2     book
4    2     book
5    2     book
6    3     book
7    3     book
8    3     book
9    4  unknown
10   4  picture
```

Comment: Looks like OP changed their question >:(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ this does not make sense ... totally change his question ...

Comment: Looks great now buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-`lambda` solution using `groupby` + `transform` + `any`:

```
m = df.set_index('id').valid.eq('book').groupby(level=0).transform('any')
df['valid'] = np.where(m, 'book', df.valid) 

df
    id    valid
0    1     book
1    1     book
2    1     book
3    2     book
4    2     book
5    2     book
6    3     book
7    3     book
8    3     book
9    4  unknown
10   4  picture
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Categorical Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) to re-order the "valid" column.

Then produce a mapping series after dropping duplicates and apply this to your original dataframe.

```
df['valid'] = df['valid'].astype('category')

df['valid'] = df['valid'].cat.set_categories(\
                 list(set(df['valid'])-{'Unknown'})+['Unknown'], ordered=True)

s = df.sort_values('valid').drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['valid']

df['valid'] = df['id'].map(s)
```

As a side effect, you may see other benefits, e.g. checking of appropriate items in 'valid' column, memory savings, performance improvements.

**Result**

```
    id    valid
0    1     book
1    1     book
2    1     book
3    2     book
4    2     book
5    2     book
6    3     book
7    3     book
8    3     book
9    4  unknown
10   4  unknown
```